# How do I reverse the order of submit and preview button?

Tags: nodes, forms

I need to change the submit and preview button order in the node edit form in Drupal 7.
By default the submit button shows first the preview button, But I need vice versa.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use `hook_form_alter()` in a custom module to make the submit button heavier than the preview button:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'MYNODETYPE_node_form') {
    $form['actions']['preview']['#weight'] = $form['actions']['submit']['#weight']-1;
  }
}
```

Just change the module name and form id accordingly.

Comment: can we remove the node form on preview page .?

Comment: Please ask that as a new question. Chatty threads with multiple questions are discouraged here.